# Hibernate - "detached entity passed to persist" error for already persisted child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence

I have an entity, which is already persisted and want to add it to a newly generated parent entity (not yet persisted). If i try to persisted the parent then, i get the error "detached entity passed to persist: model.Child". I think i have to somehow call a "entityManager.merge()" for the child instead of a "entityManager.persist()". But i do not explicitly call the persist. This is handled by the "cascade = CascadeType.ALL" annotation. Can i tell hibernate somehow to do a merge here, if the entity already exists?

By the way: If i first persist the parent, then add the child and then persist the parent again -> It works (But makes my application logic much more complicated).

Here my code:

```
public class App 
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {

        // I have a child object (in the real app 
        //this is a user object and already persisted
        Child child = new Child();
        HibernateHelper.persist(child);

        Parent parent = new Parent();

        parent.addChildren(child);
        // throws the exception "detached entity passed to persist: model.Child"
        HibernateHelper.persist(parent);

        Parent newParent = HibernateHelper.find(Parent.class, parent.getId());
        assertEquals(1,  newParent.getChildren().size());

    }
}
```

My "child" entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {

    public Child(){}

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private Parent parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }



}
```

My "parent" entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
public class Parent {

    public Parent(){}

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
    public void addChildren(Child child){
        children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

The persist helper method (looks the same for the child)

```
public static void persist(Parent entity){

    EntityManager entityManager = null;
    try {
        entityManager = beginTransaction();

        if(entity.getId()!=null){
            entityManager.merge(entity);
        }else{
            entityManager.persist(entity);
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return;
    }finally{
        if(entityManager != null)
            entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to always use EntityManager.merge. In case a new entity is passed it is persisted, in case a detached entity is passed it is merged into the current persistence context.

Comment: Is there any downside to this approach?

Comment: merge returns a managed instance, persist converts the parameter into a managed instance. Further changes to the object after calling your persist method will not be reflected to the database, but you already had that in your current implementation when merge was invoked